# Django character wrong encoding for Ajax request

Tags: ajax, django, unicode

I have a form which is generated from a database. In the database I have strings such as 'Española' which will become options in a drop down menu.

A the moment my html looks like:

```
<option value="Española">Española</option>
```

I am using these values for a dynamic part of the form from which I need to send AJAX requests.

I can see that, when using IE, the header is like so:

```
GET /collections/find_island?island_group=Espa�ola HTTP/1.1" 500 63206
```

when it should be:

```
GET /collections/find_island/?island_group=Espa%C3%B1ola HTTP/1.1" 200 164
```

As generated by other browsers.

Is there some way I can get this output in my template:

```
<option value="Espa%C3%B1ola">Española</option>
```

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT:

My form:

```
def form(forms.Form):
    ...
    island_group = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    required=False,
    label=ugettext_lazy('Island Group'), 
    initial=None,
    queryset=Localityonline.objects.values_list('islandgroup', flat=True).distinct('islandgroup').order_by('islandgroup'), 
    empty_label=ugettext_lazy("Not Specified"), 
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":'searchfield', "onChange":'getIslandName()'})
)
```

the javascript:

```
function getIslandName(lang) {
var islandGroup = document.getElementById("id_island_group").value;

if (islandGroup == '') {
    // if Not Specified re-selected then set data to null and bypass updatePage()
    var data = null; 
    update_select($('select[name=island_name]'), data);
} 
else {
    var url = "../collections/find_island?island_group=" + islandGroup;
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
    request.send(null);
    }    
}
```

Comment: How do you get the value and use it in GET by javascript?

Comment: A queryset from the db. See Edit for what this looks like.

Comment: I mean the JS part. `getIslandName`

Comment: See my Edit to include the js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `encodeURI` in javascipt to give the encoded value that you are looking for.  Perhaps mozilla and chrome do it automatically and IE doesn't???

```
encodeURI('Española')
// "Espa%C3%B1ola"

var url = "../collections/find_island?island_group=" + encodeURI(islandGroup);
```

or encode the whole url I don't know which one makes more sense...

[Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI